# Get List of Restaurants from New York city using Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I want to get the list of all the restaurant pages that are based in New York using Facebook Graph API. I have downloaded the PHP-SDK and now I am stuck with this problem. I only need the id of the restaurant pages.

```
<?php
  $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=restaurant&type=page";
  $result = file_get_contents($url,true);
  $result = json_decode($result);
  //print_r($result);
  $i = 25;
  for($a=0;$a<$i;$a++) {
$restaurantName = $result->data[$a]->name;
$restaurantCategory = $result->data[$a]->category;
$restaurantPage_id = $result->data[$a]->id;
}

?>
```

Now as you can see in the above code I get all types of category(like APP, Food & Beverage, Company, etc) and from different parts of the world. I only want restaurants from New York and really don't know how to filter the result.

Any help will really be appreciated.

Comment: naive question: what happens if you search for "restaurant new york" in the url ? (`q` parameter, maybe encode whitespace with `%20`)

Comment: You just made my day. I checked it and its working fine. But can you just tell me if there is any way that I can restrict the category to "Restaurant/Cafe". I know I can use the PHP loop for that but thinking of other way around. Really Thanks

Comment: I don't know, sorry. Maybe have a look to the API documentation ? I'm not a user of facebook graph API so I can't help you more than that

Answer (score 5):

Replace this url,

```
$url ="https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=restaurant&type=place&center=40.714623,-74.006605&distance=16000&access_token=`Your_Access_Token`";
```

New York center latitude=40.714623 & longitude=-74.006605.
An access token is required to request this resource.

May this help you.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will give it try and let you know through this forum.

Comment: This will give you anything with "Restaurant" in the name near New York, but won't filter on the category "Restaurant" -- is there a way to add that filter?

Comment: At last I couldn't find any other solution. So I got the restaurant list of New York from SINGLE PLATFORM and then used the Facebook Graph to get my required results. in the 'q' parameter I used the restaurant name that I got from Single Platform