# How can I get facebook's list of restaurant pages and show that list on my own created website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

First of all I want to say that I'm pretty new when it comes to APIs, but I want to practice. **Is it possible to use** I don't know, maybe **facebook for developers to gain access to whole restaurants list from facebook**? I wish I could **create website with rating** of that restaurants with aesthetic layout and some filters to look up for only interesting places.

Help me please, and if it is not possible **could anyone give my any alternative way to do similar website**?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe using web scrapping techniques?

Comment: Is it legal? I've never heard about it.

Comment: This question might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258589/get-list-of-restaurants-from-new-york-city-using-facebook-graph-api

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for duplicated question.

Comment: scraping is not allowed on facebook, don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd get an access token to the Facebook Graph API, then look at an example like this:

[Get List of Restaurants from New York city using Facebook Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258589/get-list-of-restaurants-from-new-york-city-using-facebook-graph-api)